# Parsing json and convert Double to String (Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1098a1b90) to 'NSNumber')

Tags: json, swift

I have a Swift struct like this.

```
func parseData() {

    fetchedProduct = []
    let url = "http://www.koulourades.gr/api/products/get/?category=proionta"

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task =  session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if  (error != nil) {
            print("Error")
        }
        else{
            do {
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSArray

                for eachFetchedProduct in fetchedData {
                    let eachProduct = eachFetchedProduct as! [String : Any]
                    let title = eachProduct ["ProductTitle"] as! String
                    let price = eachProduct ["ProductPrice"] as! Double

                    self.fetchedProduct.append(Product(title: title, price: price))
                }

                print(self.fetchedProduct)
                print(self.fetchedProduct.count)
            } catch {
              print("Error 2")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()     
}

class Product {

    var title: String
    var price: Double

    init(title: String, price: Double) {
        self.title = title
        self.price = price
    }
}
```

From an API, I get the following JSON response.(it's in Greek language and  there are more properties i just write some of these)

```
[  
   {

   "ProductTitle":"\u03a0\u03c1\u03b1\u03bb\u03af\u03bd\u03b1 OREO",

   "ProductSummary":"\u03bc\u03c0\u03b9\u03c3\u03ba\u03bf\u03c4\u03bf",

   "ProductPrice":"1.50",

   "ProductPriceGross":"1.86",

   "ProductPriceWithDiscount":"0.00", 

   "ProductImage":"koulouri_tyri_gemisto_philadelphia_galopoula_ntomata[1].jpg",

   },
...
]
```

but I want to take only the **ProductPrice** and the **ProductTitle**

Swift tells me this: **Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1098a1b90) to 'NSNumber' (0x108eaa320)**.

And, when I try to take only the ProductTitle which is String tells me this:
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The `ProductPrice` value in your JSON is a string, not a double and that is what the exception is telling you; you can't force downcast a string to a double.  You need to convert it via the `Double` initialiser `let price = Double(eachProduct ["ProductPrice"])`

Comment: @Paulw11, you should post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it. I was about to say the same thing but you beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ProductPrice` value in your JSON is a string, not a double and that is what the exception is telling you; you can't force downcast a string to a double.

You need to convert it via the Double initialiser

From the information you have posted, you should not get an exception when accessing `ProductTitle`, although force unwrapping/downcasting is best avoided.  Check carefully for typing errors in your key names.

A "safer" approach (that also avoids `NSArray` which is best practice in Swift):

```
if let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [[String:Any]] {

    for eachProduct in fetchedData {

       if let title = eachProduct ["ProductTitle"] as? String,
          let price = eachProduct ["ProductPrice"] as? String,
          let doublePrice = Double(price) {
              self.fetchedProduct.append(Product(title: title, price: doublePrice))

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Once the compound `if let` statement succeeds, `price` is a double. No need for the extra `let doublePrice = Double(price) ?? 0`. That cast is redundant. Now, putting an else on the `if let` that assigns a value of  0 might be reasonable...

Comment: Thanks for that; I accidentally copied the `as? Double` from the question. It should be `as? String` since the JSON contains a string.  the `Double(string)` initialiser does return an optional

Comment: Actually, it is probably best if the code just skips creating the product if it doesn't have the mandatory fields

Comment: Good point. the `as? Double` would fail on a string. I was thinking that was a cast, but it's not.

Comment: Yes..it works!The only i added is

for eachFetchedProduct in fetchedData {
                            let eachProduct = eachFetchedProduct

Comment: Why do you need that extra constant?  Swift is copy-on-modify so it won’t impact performance in any noticeable way, but why do you need it?

Comment: because    for eachProduct FetchedProduct in fetchedData { 

says expected 'in' after for-each patern

for a resason after for ,  needs eachFetchedProduct or eachProduct

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a cut/paste error. I have fixed that